# What are all the files in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\ on Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

What creates them? There is over 1GB of files and I need to free up some space on the C drive ASAP.. Can I change the location they are saved to another drive? Can I delete them?

Comment: What kind of files are there? I could not find that dictionary on a few different Server 2003 machines. File names and extensions would help.

Comment: Insight here...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241162

Comment: And here...http://microsoft-server-operating-systems.hostweb.com/TopicMessages/microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs/1913485/1/Default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give much information as to what type of files they are, but on my server, they are catalog files, which is how Windows Backup keeps track of what is on each backup set. You can probably purge the older ones.

To free up space, I would do this:

1. Install and run CCleaner.
2. Make sure that all the service pack and hot fix uninstalls are deleted from c:\windows (they are hidden folders, and all start with $)
3. Run windirstat and see if there is anything else that is large, and taking up space.

http://windirstat.info/ (it is free)